# Opensource Collaboration tools

Tags: java, collaboration, forums

I am working on a portal and right now has static content. My web server is tomcat. I am planning to add collaboration among users using Forums and Blogs. From your experience can you share how to integrate blogs and forum applications for your websites. I prefer to have the blogs and forums functionality within my portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether this tool is applicable for you.

http://pebble.sourceforge.net/

Pebble is a lightweight, open source, Java EE blogging tool. It's small, fast and feature-rich with unrivalled ease of installation and use.

Comment: The feature docs says that it hosts blogs. Does it allow to host forums as well? I dont forums in the feature list.

Comment: I am not explore this tool fully,please check the documentation for more details.